# How to fix black screen when replacing SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mapbox

I'm creating a simple application using Mapbox (using mapbox-android-sdk:7.1.0 ) in a fragment.

I have an activity which is composed of a FrameLayout (containing the Fragments) and a button.

At the beginning, the Fragment1 (containing the map) is displayed in the FrameLayout. When the user clicks on the button, the Fragment1 is replaced by the Fragment2 (containing a TextView).

During the transition there is a short black screen.

When I use Mapbox in an activity I don't have any problem, It seems to happen when the method onDestroyView() is called.

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Load Fragment1 containing the map
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment1()).commit();


        AppCompatButton button = findViewById(R.id.btn_changeFragment);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Load Fragment2 containing a TextView
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment2()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Fragment1.java :**

```
public class Fragment1 extends SupportMapFragment {
    private MapView mapView;

    public Fragment1(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(getContext(), getString(R.string.mapbox_token));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.LIGHT, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                        // Configure the map
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this Attribute app:mapbox_renderTextureMode="true" while loading mapview inside the fragment did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with how MapFragment's behave: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/9570. Per the ticket, there are currently two possible ways to resolve this issue in your app.

**Either**:

1. Use a bitmap of the map in an `ImageView` while transitioning instead of a `MapView`. You can then make the MapView visible as part of the `OnMapReady` callback in your activity.

**Or**:

2. Use a `TextureView` implementation instead. This can be enabled via [MapboxMapOptions](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.1/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMapOptions.html#textureMode-boolean-) or `.xml` attributes. You should also keep in mind that this solution may lead to performance issues down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first solution proposed by @riastrad but I didn´t find how to make a bitmap of the mapView ( I always had a white screen with the mapbox logo at the bottom).

Anyway, I tried to use `setAlpha` to change the opacity of the mapView, and it works. I don't realy know why it doesn't work with `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

So before to load the Fragment2, I call a method from Fragment1 to set the opacity of the mapView to 0.

#### MainActivity.java

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if(currentFragment instanceof Fragment1){
            // Set the opacity of the mapView to 0
            ((Fragment1) currentFragment).transition();
            // Load Fragment2 containing a TextView
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment2()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
});
```

#### Fragment1.java

```
public void transition(){
    mapView.setAlpha(0f);
}
```